# Vue.js 3 with Esbuild a

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, esbuild

I am trying to use Vue.js 3 inside a Rails app to use a few components but I got this error in dev console

> [Vue warn]: Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not
> supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue"
> to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js".

I tried installing using the "[without build tools](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools)" version and it works.

**app/javascript/components/index.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import MyComponent from './dropdown'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    createApp(MyComponent).mount('#app')
})
```

**app/javascript/components/dropdown.js**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            message: 'Hello Vue!'
          }
    },
}
```

**app/views/index.html**

```
<div id="app">{{ message }}</div>
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "vue": "^3.2.36"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node esbuild.config.js",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*esbuild* doesn't have an alias feature out of the box. Just import esm bundler directly:

```
import { createApp } from "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js"
```

There is a plugin for configuring aliases `esbuild-plugin-alias`:

*https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-plugin-alias*